# Can't deploy Vue app in production

Tags: npm, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to deploy a Vue app in production. After executing the command "npm run build" I copied "index.html" and "dist" into my apache root directory. When I access to my website, the next mistake appears:

**external "vue-axios":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: vue is not defined**

Do you know if I have to do an additional step before deploying my app?

PX: This app works properly by using "npm run dev"

Comment: Can you show your package.json? Are you sure you have `vue` in `dependencies`, not `devDependencies`?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  },

Comment: It is part of my package.json, thank for your help

Comment: Is `vue-axios` in `dependencies `?

Comment: please provide the `index.html`

Comment: it was not, I just added it but the same error is still appearing. This is my current "dependecies": __"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },]__

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>soporte_7x24</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry for the mesh way in which I comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the reason you are getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: vue is not defined` is likely due to the fact that you are requiring your source code bundle *before* you are requiring Vue.js. (Assuming you don't have `vue` bundled into your source)

So when the browser hits `<script src="/dist/build.js"></script>`, any code that relies on vue is going to fail.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="es"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>soporte_7x24</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/…; crossorigin="anonymous"> </head> <body> <div id="app"></div> <script src="/dist/build.js"></script> <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/…;"/> </body> </html>
```

Change the order of `<script src="/dist/build.js"></script>` so that it is after `<script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/…;"/>`

Comment: Done, I exchanged the two previous lines in "index.html", I added "vue-axios" in "dependences" and I deleted "externals" in "webpack.config.js" . Now it works properly.